# Web Deploy 3.0 Installation Fails

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, msi, deployment

I am having difficulty installing Microsoft Web Deploy 3.0 to a Windows Server 2008 R2 box. I have tried installing with both the Web Platform Installer and the MSI package but installation fails while trying to execute the MSI custom action **ExecuteRegisterUIModuleCA**.

This server is a VM and a member of a farm but shared config is disabled while I'm installing.

Here's the point at which it fails in the MSI log (starting at line 1875):

```
MSI (s) (80:FC) [15:29:01:358]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=IISBeginTransactionCA,,)
MSI (s) (80:FC) [15:29:01:374]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=IISBeginTransactionCA,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=IISBeginTransactionCA,)
MSI (s) (80:A8) [15:29:01:374]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI6C6A.tmp, Entrypoint: IISBeginTransactionCA
MSI (s) (80:FC) [15:29:01:436]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=IISRollbackTransactionCA,,)
MSI (s) (80:FC) [15:29:01:436]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=IISRollbackTransactionCA,ActionType=3329,Source=BinaryData,Target=IISRollbackTransactionCA,)
MSI (s) (80:FC) [15:29:01:436]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=IISCommitTransactionCA,,)
MSI (s) (80:FC) [15:29:01:436]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=IISCommitTransactionCA,ActionType=3585,Source=BinaryData,Target=IISCommitTransactionCA,)
MSI (s) (80:FC) [15:29:01:436]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=IISExecuteCA,,)
MSI (s) (80:FC) [15:29:01:452]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=IISExecuteCA,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=IISExecuteCA,CustomActionData=1^3^21^WebDeployment_Current^154^Microsoft.Web.Deployment.UI.PackagingModuleProvider, Microsoft.Web.Deployment.UI.Server, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35^1^1^0^^1^3^28^DelegationManagement_Current^171^Microsoft.Web.Management.Delegation.DelegationModuleProvider, Microsoft.Web.Management.Delegation.Server, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35^1^1^0^^1^7^38^system.webServer/management/delegation^4^Deny^16^MachineToWebRoot^0^^3^yes^1^7^31^system.webServer/wdeploy/backup^4^Deny^20^MachineToApplication^0^^2^no^)
MSI (s) (80:84) [15:29:01:452]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI6CB9.tmp, Entrypoint: IISExecuteCA
1: IISCA IISExecuteCA : Begin CA Setup 
1: IISCA IISExecuteCA : CA 'ExecuteRegisterUIModuleCA' completed with return code hr=0x8007000d 
1: IISCA IISExecuteCA : CA 'IISExecuteCA' completed with return code hr=0x8007000d 
1: IISCA IISExecuteCA : End CA Setup 
CustomAction IISExecuteCA returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 15:29:05: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

I can't seem to find any information regarding this particular issue; can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of digging I finally found the solution.

There were two duplicated entries in the administration.config's location\modules section: Rewrite & PlatformInstaller. Removing these duplicates allowed the installation to complete successfully.

Comment: Hmm I'm getting the same error but don't see any duplicates in my administration.config